# Sublime Text 2: How to disable auto indentation on new lines after brackets?

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation, auto-indent, code-editor

I try to work with Sublime Text 2.

In Javascript, whenever I type a bracket and press ENTER, an extra indentation is added like this ("|" symbolizes the cursor):

```
    if () {
        |
```

If I set "auto_indent" to false in Sublime Text 2 settings, whenever I type a bracket and press ENTER, the cursor moves to the beginning of the line, like this :

```
    if () {
|
```

I want the cursor moves at the same horizontal point as the bracket, like this:

```
    if () {
    |
```

Do you have an idea to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite get the last example you gave use above, so I'll just gave you some information I know, hopefully, there will be something useful to you. According to [official indentation documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html), there is a "indent_to_bracket" option, you may give it a shot.

And I know a sublime text plugin called [SublimeBracketeer](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeBracketeer) that seems does the heavy lifting for you. Maybe you can give it a shot.